# Its saying that: Execution failed. ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10 what is the meaning?

Tags: python-3.x

...Its saying that:

> Execution failed. ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10

what is the meaning?...

```
L=input("\n")
N=input("\n")
for i in range(int(N)):
    W=input()
    H=input()
    if int(W)<int(L) or int(H)<int(L):
        print("UPLOAD ANOTHER\n")
    elif int(W)>=int(L) and int(H)>=int(L):
        if int(W)==int(H):
            print("ACCEPTED\n")
        else:
            print("CROP IT\n")
```

Comment: Have you read this https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and this https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve?

Comment: When I run this code as posted I don't get that error.  In fact I don't get any errors.  Although you don't need to add the new line characters in your input as `input()` automatically moves to the new line with a new call.